X apps without menu right and bottom border
I am not sure why, but xfontsel and other X applications do not have the bottom and right borders in the dropdown menu.
I believe there should exist a Xresources attribute to make the border appear, but I could not figure it out.
I tried to use appres xfontsel or editres but no luck so far.
So my question is: how can I add those missing borders?


I found a solution for this problem. If I add displayList in the ~/.Xresources it works.
The complete solution is as follows (note that red and blue are just for demonstration):
*SimpleMenu.borderWidth: 0
*SimpleMenu*displayList: \
  foreground blue;lines 1,-1,-1,-1,-1,1; \
  foreground red;lines -1,0,0,0,0,-1

I found this by exploring the folder /etc/X11/app-defaults. However, I do not know what the format/specification of displayList means.
